# Multivariate analysis. Hypothesis income variable increases 2 outcome variables simultaneously

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-regression

I am working on an epidemic analysis on a known blood disease. My outcome variables are two, lets call them A and B. I have already two income variables lets call them c and d, that have been proved to significantly affect A and B and their ratio A/B (also B/A). We want to analyse the effect of a new variable, lets call it e. All variables `A,B,c,d and e` are continuous. Our theory is that e does only increase A and B simultaneously, keeping their ratio constant with increasing e.

When throwing up the simple univariate models `A ~ c+d+e` and `B ~ c+d+e`, e proves to contribute significantly, but more strongly for B.

When testing the effect on the ratio `A/B ~ c+d+e`, e is NOT significant, but when you turn this around that is `B/A ~ c+d+e`, e is significant.

I also set up an multivariate model in R like

`summary(manova(lm(cbind(A,B) ~ c + d + e, data=data)))`

There every variable `c,d and e` came out very significant, but I am new to multivariate analysis so I am not sure weather this is done correctly.

In addition I calculated principal components of the variables A and B, lets call it PS_AB. Then I ran model:

`PC_AB ~ c + d + e`

There e came out very significant p ~= e-15.

From my preliminary result it seems so that e is significant, but I am not convinced. So my question is, do you see anything that I might have done wrongly or do you have any idea on a better way to do this analysis?